# ¿Uso de presente en vez de subjuntivo?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, subjuntivo, subordinadas

En Duolingo acaba de salir el curso de catalán y empecé a hacerlo, todo normal hasta que llegué a estas oraciones:

> No como, aunque cocinas conejo con verdura.
>
> *No menjo malgrat cuines conill amb verdura.*
>
> Aunque cocinas verdura con pollo, yo no como.
>
> *Encara que cuines verdura amb pollastre jo no menjo.*
>
> No bebes, aunque el vino es mio.
>
> *No beus malgrat el vi és meu.*

Me parecieron muy extrañas, ya pasó un día y ya las asimilo mejor pero inicialmente me extrañé demasiado por la falta del subjuntivo. Pregunté en las foros de las oraciones y un hablante de catalán se extrañó de que me hubiese extrañado. Me dijo que funciona igual en español decir las oraciones de arriba en tiempo presente como decirlas con subjuntivo:

> No como, aunque cocin**e**s conejo con verdura.
>
> Aunque cocin**e**s verdura con pollo, yo no como.
>
> No beb**a**s, aunque el vino **sea** mio.

Supongo que en las áreas cercanas a la región de influencia del catalán esto ha de funcionar igual pero ¿es así en otras partes del mundo hispanohablante?
Con lo del subjuntivo incluso siento que para que sonara normal a mis oídos haría falta un futuro:

> No como/voy a comer/comeré, aunque cocin**e**s conejo con verdura.
>
> Aunque cocin**e**s verdura con pollo, yo no como/no voy a comer/comeré.

Eso tal vez podría ser cuestión de gustos pero en fin. ¿En español se pueden construir esas oraciones sin subjuntivo conservando el mismo significado? (Sobre todo en áreas lejanas al catalán o españa) Saludos!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la frase exacta en catalán? Aún a riesgo de ser off-topic aquí, hablo catalán y la traducción literal tendría un significado distinto en presente que en subjuntivo.

Comment: Ya agregué las frases en catalán.

Comment: Se confirma mi hipótesis pues. "No bebes, aunque el vino es mio" y su equivalente en catalán tienen la misma connotación: estamos en la mesa, hay vino y tú decides no beberlo. Si se usara el subjuntivo se referiría, claro está, a otra hipotética situación (o una repetida). Creo que lo esencial aquí es que lo que te comentaron en el foro no es correcto.

Answer (score 1):

## **Respuesta:**

Sí están mal escritas las frases que viste en Duolingo.

1. > No como, aunque cocinas conejo con verdura.

   No se puede leer bien, sin poner en subjuntivo el verbo de la subordinada (cocinar).
2. > Aunque cocinas verdura con pollo, yo no como.

   Es prácticamente la misma idea anterior, pero escribiendo primero la oración subordinada.
3. > No bebes, aunque el vino es mio.

   Dos opciones:

   1. Podría ser el equivalente a:

      > No estás bebiendo, aunque el vino es mío.

      que de todas maneras yo lo escribiría como:

      > No bebes (ahora), aunque el vino **sea** mío.
   2. Mal usado el **imperativo negativo** en la primera oración, donde yo escribiría:

      > No bebas, aunque el vino **sea** mío.

      - No confundirlo con un subjuntivo: ojo, si bien tienen la misma forma, decir **no bebas** o **no fumes**, no tiene nada que ver con subjuntivo, porque son imperativos negativos.

---

## **Explicación gramatical:**

Primero que todo, el contexto de las tres oraciones que viste en Duolingo corresponde al de las **Oraciones concesivas**

> **Oraciones concesivas:** son aquellas en que se expone una contrariedad a lo expresado en la oración principal, pero denotando al mismo tiempo que dicha contrariedad, aun concedida, no invalida lo afirmado en la principal. [1]

Respecto del modo verbal de la oración subordinada, tenemos:

> La oración subordinada puede ir antes, en medio o después de la oración principal; con el modo indicativo expresa objeción real, y con el subjuntivo, objeción posible. [1].

Así que, a modo de resumen, tenemos:

- Oración subordinada en indicativo: objeción real:

  > Aunque hay peligro, salgo.
  >   Recopilo los documentos, aunque sé que no están todos todavía acá.
- Oración subordinada en subjuntivo: objeción posible:

  > Aunque haya peligro, saldré.
  >   Deberás recopilar los documentos, aunque haya algunos que no encuentres.

Ahora bien, dicho lo anterior, por mi experiencia en Latinoamérica, se podría escuchar frases en modo indicativo que debieran estar en subjuntivo, y por lo general se entiende de todas maneras el mensaje. Sin embargo, en los ejemplos que mostraste, no los considero bien escritos (simplemente porque no expresan claramente el mensaje).

---

<sup>[1]: Gramática Española, Curso Superior. F.T.D. (1958). pp 305-306.</sup>